# How to feed search results straight into Google Search?

Tags: google-chrome, search

If the title isn't clear, then hopefully this description will clear it up.

What I wanted was for a user to highlight a word on any given webpage and then that word will be searched up on Google Search (as in google.com). I have explored custom search engine but I dont need to create a whole other search engine. I just need to have whatever was highlighted to be searched up in a new tab. Is there a specific from Google for this?

Thanks for your time and help.
I will be using JavaScript if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Google Chrome (as your tag indicates, to me anyways), highlighting a selection then right-click will give you the option to search with your default search engine and open the result in a new tab.

It is unclear exactly what functionality you want and what you are writing. Is it a Chrome extension?

Comment: O alright thanks. I had no idea, this was something Chrome already had this function built in.